# Cakephp Radio Buttons from Database Entries

Tags: radio-button, cakephp-2.0, radiobuttonlist

Good day!

I have a database table called Complaints which has the following fields 
id and description. Is it possible that the values in the complaints table be used as radio button input fields? Such as if the table contains 10 entries there will be 10 radio buttons.

Comment: you can, you just need to know the count and know the code how to programatically create readio buttons based on the count youre going to generate

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($data as $key=>$value){?>

<input type="radio" name="name" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" onclick=""/> 

<?php echo $value['id']; ?>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Could you provide some extra explanation surrounding the code?

Comment: if you will see the code ,what I have done is i have iterated through the data that you have in your table and for every row,i have made a radio button .the name of the radio button will remain same while the label and id will keep on changing.so you will have n number of radio buttons where each correspond to a row in your table.